# How to create custom SpringBoot Crud Repository Methods to find specific details?

Tags: spring-boot, methods, crud

So i have 5 tables as Users,Orders,Products,Ingredients and nutrients,
Each is connected to adjacent table via @ManyToOne annotation.
 What i am stuck at is how to find product details of a particular user for a particular order and similarly finding ingredients for a particular product for a particular order for a particular user and similarly for nutrients. 
I know i have to declare custom crud methods according to a given syntax and i did so but still the method is not working.

Here is the link to the git repository
https://github.com/Guneet007/API.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Specification/Querydsl** for defining custom criteria. Because we should use more than 3 parameters with **AND** suffix.

One more issue I have found in your code is that your property name not match with your method findByProductId() it should be findByProduct(Product product). Look same for others too.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: But i want to do a search by Id itself not by complete object!!

Comment: You can just set the id in the object.

Comment: Sorry But not able to get you!! Can you help me in explaining this stuff

Comment: I am saying you just set the product id in product object and findByProduct(product)

Comment: Look spring specification